# list of vectors with prescribed sum

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

Let $a\in\mathbb{N}^n$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}\!=\!\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. How can I efficiently generate the list $$\{(a_1,\ldots,a_k); a_1,\ldots,a_k\!\in\!\mathbb{N}^n\!\setminus\!\{0\}, a_1\!+\!\ldots\!+\!a_k\!=\!a\}?$$

It would also be desirable for the code to be short. My current, highly inefficient solution is:

```
Select[Tuples[Tuples[Range[0, Max @@ a], Length@a], k], 
  Plus @@ # == a && !MemberQ[#, Table[0, {i, n}]]&]
```

Comment: If there were a function that would produce all ordered partitions of length $k$ (containing zeros) of a given $x\in\mathbb{N}$, then taking tuples would solve the problem.

Comment: Look at `IntegerPartitions`...

Comment: Or better yet, Needs["Combinatorica`"] Compositions[5,3].

Comment: Just be aware of compatibility issues if you're on recent version of *Mathematica*, some posts here cover such, and docs has guide....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for, using

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

is:

```
a={2,2,1}; n=Length@a; k=3;

Select[Transpose/@Tuples[Table[Compositions[a[[i]],k],{i,n}]], !MemberQ[#,Table[0,{i,n}]]&]
```

If furthermore all tuples with at least one vector without a $0$ entry are removed, then:

```
complex = Table[Select[Transpose/@Tuples[Table[Compositions[a[[i]],k],{i,n}]], 
       !MemberQ[#,Table[0,{i,n}]] && (And@@(MemberQ[#,0]&/@#))&],{k,deg}];
Column/@complex
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's start by defining a helper function that will find all of the partitions of an integer that contains exactly `k` components:

```
partitions[n_, k_] :=
  Composition[Union, Permutations, PadRight[#, k]&] /@ IntegerPartitions[n, k] //
  Flatten[#, 1]& //
  Sort
```

We let `IntegerPartitions` do the heavy-lifting, but pad the results with zeroes so that there are always exactly `k` components.  We permute each of the results and eliminate duplicates. `Flatten` is used to undo the extra list level introduced by `Permutations`.  Finally, we `Sort` the result to impose a canonical order (this step is optional).

Here it is in action:

```
partitions[3, 3]
(*{{0,0,3},{0,1,2},{0,2,1},{0,3,0},{1,0,2},{1,1,1},{1,2,0},{2,0,1},{2,1,0},{3,0,0}}*)
```

We then use this helper function to define the main function:

```
setPartitions[a_, k_] :=
  Module[{n = Length@a, z = 0 a}
  , partitions[#, k]& /@ a //
    Tuples //
    Transpose[#, {1, 3, 2}]& //
    Select[#, FreeQ[#, z]&]&
  ]
```

This invokes the helper function on each element of `a`.  All possible combinations of the individual element partitions are then assembled using `Tuples`.  `Transpose` generates the result vector sets.  Finally, any combination involving the zero vector is removed.

Sample use:

```
setPartitions[{1, 2}, 2]
(*{{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}}*)
```

`setPartitions[{3, 5, 7}, 2]` generates the same 190 sets as the code exhibited in the question applied to the same parameters.  On my machine, the original code took 1.89s to run whereas `setPartitions` was too fast to measure (0s reported).  Notwithstanding this improvement, beware that this problem generates very large solution sets for even small increases in magnitude of `k`, `n` or the individual `a[[i]]`.  For example, `setPartitions[{3, 5, 7}, 5]` took 9.08s to generate 856,985 solutions.

**Edit**

At the suggestion of @rasher, `partitions` can be expressed more concisely thus:

```
partitions[n_, k_] :=
    Join @@ (Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {k}, Range[0, n]]) // Sort
```

Once again, the `Sort` is optional and is only there to obtain the same order of results as the code in the question.  I would recommend removing the `Sort` if that order is not crucial.

Comment: Nice, but "helper" is doing much more work than needed, try e.g. this, order of magnitude faster on smallish, faster yet as results size increases: 
`fastComp[n_, k_] := 
 Join @@ (Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {k}, Range[0, n]])`

Comment: @rasher Much nicer, thanks.  I have incorporated your suggestion as an addendum.  For `setPartitions[{3, 5, 7}, 5]`, the main function still dominates the run time as the helper optimization only shaved off about 0.12s off total time on my machine.

Comment: I have another question: How can I remove from this list all tuples of vectors $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$, where at least one $a_i$ is componentwise $\geq(1,\ldots,1)$?

Comment: The filtering is done in the call to `FreeQ`.  We could add another pattern, e.g. `FreeQ[#, z|u]&`, where `u = z + 1`.