# Distribute an integer $m$ to lists of length $n$ in all possible ways?

Tags: list-manipulation

I need a function that creates a table of all possible lists of length $n$ which contain integer entries that sum up to the same given number $m$. For example, if we consider lists of size $n=3$ and want to distribute the number $m=2$ in them the result should be:

```
n=3;
m=2;
numberDistribute[n,m]
```

> `{{2,0,0},{0,2,0},{0,0,2},{1,1,0},{1,0,1},{0,1,1}}`

Is there such a function in Mathematica? Or maybe there is a convenient way to write it? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Related: [(19486)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19486/121), [(21008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21008/121),
[(22397)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22397/121),
[(43162)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43162/121),
[(44550)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44550/121), [(62956)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/62956/121),
[(86106)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86106/121), [(92647)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92647/121).

Comment: More to be found with a [search.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=permutations+integerpartitions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
numberDistribute[n_?IntegerQ, m_?IntegerQ] :=
   Select[Tuples[Range[0, m], n], Total[#] == m &]
```

Answer (score 8):

**Proposition**

The built-in function `IntegerPartitions` can be useful here.

```
numberDistribute[n_, m_] := 
   Join @@ (Permutations /@ (PadLeft[#, n] & /@ IntegerPartitions[m, n]))
```

**Update**

To avoid mapping twice through the list generated by `IntegerPartitions`:

```
numberDistribute2[n_, m_] := 
   Join @@ ((Permutations@PadLeft[#, n]) & /@ IntegerPartitions[m, n])
```

Comment: Much faster than the other solutions, +1

Comment: This also avoids the memory problems introduced by creating large tuples.  This is a great solution - I had no idea that `IntegerPartitions` existed!

Comment: To avoid having to `Pad`, do `Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[m, {n}, Range[0, m]]`.

Comment: @march Thanks for mentioning, this is indeed nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Of the solutions so far, those based on `IntegerPartitions` by @Xavier and @march are orders of magnitude faster than those based on `Tuples` (@djphd and @eldo). Just for interest, the following method based on `FrobeniusSolve` is about 10 times faster than `Tuples`, but still much slower than `IntegerPartitions`.

```
AnotherNumberDistribute[n_,m_]:=FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, n], m]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
numberDistribute[n_, m_] :=
 Cases[Tuples[Range[0, n - 1], n], a_List /; Total@a == m]

numberDistribute[3, 2]
```

> {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

Or

```
m = 2;
n = 3;

Pick[#, Plus @@@ # - m, 0] &[Tuples[Range[0, m], n]]
```

> {{0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

Comment: For some reason the produced entries are never bigger than `n-1`, so this implementation misses some combinations for larger examples.

Comment: Except the ordering my result seems to be the result of your question

Comment: Oh, the ordering does not really matter. But I found how to fix your code: `Cases[Tuples[Range[0, m], n], a_List /; Total@a == m]` seems to work great!