# Enumerate all lists of $m$ non-negative integers that add to $n$

Tags: combinatorics, partitions

Let $x_1,\dots,x_m$ be non-negative integers such that $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i=n$, where $m,n$ are given. How can I enumerate all such lists of $m$ integers that add to $n$?

Note that `IntegerPartitions[n,{m}]` counts two such lists as one if they are a permutation of each other, but I would count them as distinct.

Thus the list I want must have $\binom{m+n-1}{m-1}$ elements.

Comment: `Apply[Sequence]@*Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n, {k}]`

Comment: Try `FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, m], n]`. (I am sure this is a dupe.)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks, that works. I didn't know that `Permutations` considered repeated elements as identical. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Thanks, also works. But AccidentalFourierTransform's answer seems faster.

Comment: Did you want non-negative integers or positive integers? The two suggestions in the comments are different.

Comment: Check the Q&A's linked from this and tell me if you find one that matches your need: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101046/121

Comment: @CarlWoll You are right, I didn't notice. I wanted non-negative integers, so actually J.M. solution is the correct one. Although the other solution can be modified to `Apply[Sequence]@*Permutations /@ (IntegerPartitions[n + k, {k}] - 1)`

Comment: Based on your comment immediately above I have marked this as I believe is correct.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I missed that. Thanks.