# Write Partition of $n$ as an $n$-tuple

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, programming

I recently asked the question ([Computationally Employ Sum over Ordered Partitions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148156/computationally-employ-sum-over-ordered-partitions?noredirect=1#comment397858_148156)) which I think I can work through.  But there's a subtelty I overlooked before that problem is even well-defined, which is maybe deserving of its own question.

I'm interested in considering **ordered** partitions of an integer $n$.  However, using a built in function like `IntegerPartitions` the output will be in the form, for example:

`{{3,0},{2,1},{1,2},{1,1,1}}`

What I would like to do is have Mathematica write these ordered partitions as $n$-tuples.  What I mean by this is best illustrated with an example.  Consider $n=3$ objects, for a small $n$ example.  There are *two* slots between the objects where we can place barriers.

$$\{\, \cdot \, | \, \cdot \, | \, \cdot \}$$

I would like the above ordered partition to be given in Mathematica by `{1,1,1}`.

$$\{\, \cdot \,  \, \cdot \, | \, \cdot \}$$

The above partition, I want to write as `{2,0,1}` because there is no barrier in the first slot.

$$\{\, \cdot \, | \, \cdot \,  \, \cdot \}$$

The above I want to write as `{1,2,0}` and of course...

$$\{\, \cdot \,  \, \cdot \,  \, \cdot \}$$

this I want to write as `{3,0,0}`.  Is there a way I can manipulate Mathematica's built-in function `IntegerPartitions` to do this for any $n$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
orderedPartitions[n_] := Flatten[#, 1] &@(Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[n]);
paddedOrderedParitions[n_] := Flatten /@ (orderedPartitions[n] 
/. {x_Integer /; x != 1 :> PadRight[{x}, x]});
```

`n=3`,

> {{3, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}

`n=5`,

> {{5, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 2, 
>     0}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 3, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 3, 0, 
>     0}, {2, 0, 2, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 0, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1, 1, 
>     1}, {1, 2, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 2, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     1}}

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!  Also, with your help earlier on that other question I think I can do what I was originally hoping.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: What's the logic for generating eg `{3,0,0,2,0}` rather than `{3,0,0,0,2}`?

Comment: OH, I see. 3,0,0 because `3` takes up 3 slots!  Smart.

Comment: `Except[1, x_Integer]` is somewhat more efficient than `x_Integer /; x != 1`